# VS Winform - How to set font bold in a control component?

Tags: winforms, custom-component

In VS 2013 on a winform, I am using textbox and combobox controls which are defined in a component.  I want to be able to turn on/off the bold font throughout the application (all the app's controls use the component) based on a user's preference.

Code in Component:

```
Private m_Bold As Font

Public Property Bold() As Font

    Get
        Return Me.m_Bold
    End Get

    Set(value As Font)
        If SV.FontBold = True Then
            Me.m_Bold = New Font(Me.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
        Else
            Me.m_Bold = New Font(Me.Font, FontStyle.Regular)
        End If
    End Set

End Property
```

SV.FontBold is a shared public boolean set for each user at startup.

There are no errors, but the controls display regular font, not bold, at runtime.

Comment: Where do you set this bold font on your children controls ?

Comment: This code just sets a private field.  It doesn't set the Font property of the controls.  So sure, they don't change.

Comment: To mrlucmorin: I set them in the property sheet.  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: To Hans Passant: This is the same basic scheme I use to set other properties in my custom components for a textbox, combobox, listbox, and datetimepicker.  However, Font properties cannot be changed but I can apply a new one.  I did test this (cboPerson.Font = New Font(cboPerson.Font, FontStyle.Bold) on a winform and it worked fine.  Now I'm trying to use the same technique in my custom component.